# Проблема с MySQL(PHP)

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Прилагаю код скрипта:
это админка для редактирования фото(перевернуть, удалить), инфо о фото - адреса хранятся в СУБД.

```
>     <?php $mysql_host = "localhost"; $mysql_database = "webaz_avtomobil";
> $mysql_user = "webaz_cars";
> $mysql_password = "cisokoW4i"; $db =
> mysql_connect
> ($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password);
> mysql_select_db ($mysql_database,$db);
> mysql_set_charset('utf8');
>     $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
>     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM car_ann WHERE id=".$id);
>     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
>     $images = json_decode($row['gallery'],1);
>     if (isset($_GET['left'])) {
>         if ($num >= 0 && $num < sizeof($images)) {
>             $el = (int) $_GET['left'];
>             $cyr_el = array($images[$el]);
>             unset($images[$el]);
>             array_splice($images, $el-1, 0, $cyr_el);
>             $query = mysql_query("UPDATE car_ann SET
> gallery='".json_encode($images)."'
> WHERE id=".$id);
>             echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success'));
> 
>         } else {
>             echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error'));
> 
>         }
>         exit();
>     } else if (isset($_GET['right'])) {
>         if ($num >= 0 && $num < sizeof($images)) {
>             $el = (int) $_GET['right'];
>             $cyr_el = array($images[$el]);
>             unset($images[$el]);
>             array_splice($images, $el+1, 0, $cyr_el);
>             $query = mysql_query("UPDATE car_ann SET
> gallery='".json_encode($images)."'
> WHERE id=".$id);
>             echo json_encode(array('status'=>'success'));
> 
>         } else {
>             echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error'));
> 
>         }
>         exit();
>     } else if (isset($_GET['delete'])) {
>         $num = (int) $_GET['delete'];
>         if ($num >= 0 && $num < sizeof($images)) {
>             unlink(dirname(__FILE__).'/cars_images/'.$id.'/'.$images[$num]);
>             unse($timages[$num]);
>             $query = mysql_query("UPDATE car_ann SET
> gallery='".json_encode($images)."'
> WHERE id=".$id);
>         } else {
>             echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error'));
> 
>         }
>         exit();
>     } else {
>         $html = '';
>         $i = 0;
>         foreach ($images as $key => $value) {
>             $html .= '
>             <div class="template-download">
>                 <div class="preview">
>                     <a href="/cars/cars_images/'.$id.'/'.$value.'">
>                         <img src="/cars/cars_images/'.$id.'/'.$value.'"
> width="100" height="80">
>                     </a>
>                 </div>
>                 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs rotate"
> data-name="/cars/cars_images/'.$id.'/'.$value.'">
>                     <i class="icon-undo icon-white"></i>
>                     <span></span>
>                 </button>
>                 <div class="btn-group">
>                     <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs left"
> data-num="'.$i.'" data-id="'.$id.'">
>                             <i class="icon-long-arrow-left
> icon-white"></i>
>                         <span></span>
>                     </button>
>                     <button class="btn btn-info btn-xs right"
> data-num="'.$i.'" data-id="'.$id.'">
>                             <i class="icon-long-arrow-right
> icon-white"></i>
>                         <span></span>
>                     </button>
>                 </div>
>                 <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete"
> data-num="'.$i.'" data-id="'.$id.'">
>                         <i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i>
>                     <span>Удалить</span>
>                 </button>
>             </div>
>             ';
>             $i++;
>         }
>     } ?> <html> <head>
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css">
>     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
>     <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
> </head> <body> <?php echo $html; ?>
> <script
> src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script>
>     $(document).on('click', '.template-download .rotate',
> function(e) {
>         var cyr_button = $(this);
>         $(cyr_button).hide();
>         var name = $(this).data('name');
>         $.ajax({
>             url:'server/php/?rotate&file=' +
> encodeURIComponent(name)
>         }).done(function() {
>             var a = $(cyr_button).parent().find('.preview
> a');
>             var href = a.attr('href');
>             queryPos = href.indexOf('?');
>             if(queryPos != -1) href = href.substring(0, queryPos);
>             a.attr('href', href + '?' + Math.random());
>             var img = $(cyr_button).parent().find('.preview
> img');
>             var src = img.attr('src');
>             queryPos = src.indexOf('?');
>             if(queryPos != -1) src = src.substring(0, queryPos);
>             img.attr('src', src + '?' + Math.random());
>             $(cyr_button).show();
>         }).fail(function() {
>             alert('Неудача!!!');
>             $(cyr_button).show();
>         });
>         e.preventDefault();
>     });
>     $(document).on('click', '.template-download .delete',
> function(e) {
>         var cyr_button = $(this);
>         $(cyr_button).hide();
>         var num = $(this).data('num');
>         var id = $(this).data('id');
>         $.ajax({
>             url:'admin.php?delete='+num+'&id='+id
>         }).done(function() {
>             $(cyr_button).parent().remove();
>         }).fail(function() {
>             alert('Неудача!!!');
>             $(cyr_button).show();
>         });
>         e.preventDefault();
>     });
>     $.fn.moveUp = function() {
>         $.each(this, function() {
>             $(this).after($(this).prev());   
>         });
>     };
>     $.fn.moveDown = function() {
>         $.each(this, function() {
>             $(this).before($(this).next());   
>         });
>     };
>     $(document).on('click', '.template-download .left',
> function(e) {
>         var cyr_button = $(this);
>         $(cyr_button).hide();
>         var num = $(this).data('num');
>         var id = $(this).data('id');
>         $.ajax({
>             url:'admin.php?left='+num+'&id='+id
>         }).done(function() {
>             $(cyr_button).parent().parent().moveUp();
>             $(cyr_button).show();
>         }).fail(function() {
>             alert('Неудача!!!');
>             $(cyr_button).show();
>         });
>         e.preventDefault();
>     });
>     $(document).on('click', '.template-download .right',
> function(e) {
>         var cyr_button = $(this);
>         $(cyr_button).hide();
>         var num = $(this).data('num');
>         var id = $(this).data('id');
>         $.ajax({
>             url:'admin.php?right='+num+'&id='+id
>         }).done(function() {
>             $(cyr_button).parent().parent().moveDown();
>             $(cyr_button).show();
>         }).fail(function() {
>             alert('Неудача!!!');
>             $(cyr_button).show();
>         });
>         e.preventDefault();
>     }); </script> </body> </html>
```

Вся проблема в том, что доступы к СУБД верные, таблицы правильные, а вылазит ошибка:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/webaz/public_html/testpanel/annoncement/admin.php on line 50

Помогите исправить пожалуйста! Что не так?

Comment: [depricated](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-connect.php)

    Данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет 
    удалено в будущем. Используйте вместо него MySQLi или PDO_MySQL. 
    Смотрите также инструкцию MySQL: выбор API и соответствующий FAQ 
    для получения более подробной информации. Альтернативы для данной 
    функции:

[mysqli_connect()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php)

[PDO::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.construct.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не ошибка, это предупреждение.
а говорит оно о том что в строке ниже $images не является массивом.

```
     foreach ($images as $key => $value) {
```

Comment: так а как исправить скрипт?

Comment: Невидя базы данных ничего сказать немогу кроме того что

     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM car_ann WHERE id=".$id);
     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
     $images = json_decode($row['gallery'],1);
Собственно json_decode($row['gallery'],1) - не возвращает массив)

смотрите не пуста ли база, и что возвращается в $row['gallery'] и что происходит после json_decode

Comment: таблица car_ann, поле gallery, содержание для проверяемого элемента в скрипте:
thumbcar/dir534/img-Mercedes-Benz-A 160-2680677.jpg